# Canceling a thread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, pthreads, semaphore

I'm trying to cancel a thread that way :

```
pthread_cancel(threads[id]);
```

And I release the mutex before cancelling the thread.

And after that I need to restart it because it was causing a DeadLock

```
usleep(1);
pthread_create(&threads[id], NULL, aFunction, &id );
usleep(1);
pthread_join(threads[id], NULL);
usleep(1);
```

I tried to remove pthread_join, but no luck.

This is a big part of the code :

```
    #define LEFT(i) i
    #define RIGHT(i) (i+1) % N 
    #define CreateSemaphore(s,v)   sem_init( &s, 0, v)
    #define WaitSemaphore(s)       sem_wait( &s )
    #define SignalSemaphore(s)     sem_post( &s )
    #define ReleaseSemaphore(s)    sem_destroy( &s )

    void restart(int id) {

        release(id, LEFT(id));
        int res;

        if (allocated[id][RIGHT(id)] == 1) {

            release(id, RIGHT(id));

        }
        res = pthread_cancel(threads[id]);
        if (res != 0) {
            perror("Thread cancelation failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        usleep(1);

        res = pthread_create(&threads[id], NULL, aFunction, &id );

        usleep(1);
            if (res  != 0 ) {
                fprintf( stderr, "Error creating the thread %d \n", id );           
                exit( 1 );
            }
        printf("Waiting for thread to finish...\n");
        res = pthread_join(threads[id], NULL);

        if (res != 0) {
            perror("Thread join failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else
         printf("Passed join...\n");

        usleep(1);
    }

void * aFunction( void *i )
{
    int value = *((int *)i);

    while ( 1 ){

        think( value );    
        take( value );    
        eat( value );    
        drop( value );   
    }    
    pthread_exit( NULL );
}

void take( int i ) {
            request(i, LEFT(i)); 
            WaitSemaphore( fork[LEFT(i)] );

            allocation(i, LEFT(i));

            usleep(100);
            request(i, RIGHT(i)); 

            WaitSemaphore( fork[RIGHT(i)] );

            allocation(i, RIGHT(i));

            usleep(100);

}

void drop( int i )
{

    SignalSemaphore( forks[LEFT(i)] ); 
    release(i, LEFT(i));

    usleep(100);

    SignalSemaphore( forks[RIGHT(i)] ); 
    release(i, RIGHT(i));  

    usleep(100);

}

void release(int id, int f) {

    WaitSemaphore(mutex[f]);

        beingUsed[id][f] = 0;
        currentAvail[f]  = 1;

    SignalSemaphore(mutex[f]);

}
```

Comment: If a thread is causing a deadlock, it means it was using some sort of resource with a mutex(or similar). Destroying the thread is not enough, as you also have to release the resources.

Comment: Show your code compelely, the `dead lock` depends on your `aFunction` or  other thread. No Code, No truth.

Comment: Well, I have to cause a deadlock and fix it.

And I do release the mutex before I cancel the thread.

Comment: @CharlesWelton: At least under POSIX `sem_wait()` is defined to **be** a cancellation point: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html (scroll down to *Cancellation Points*).

Comment: When you attached gdb to your deadlocked process, and examined the threads and their call stacks, where was it blocked?

Answer (score 0):

did you try with pthread_exit(1) inside the thread code? This is other way to finish the running thread when it finishes it work.